# Windows' "open with" with java and a jar file

Tags: windows, java, windows-explorer, file-association, jar

I use the [rest-client](http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/) to test REST APIs. It is basically just a .jar file, that is called via `java -jar rest-client.jar`. The rest-client uses two file extensions, in my case `.rcq`, to store data in files.

I want to let the explorer open `.rcq` files with `java -jar rest-client.jar <infile>`, however, if I configure it (via GUI) to use the JAR alone, it obviously doesn't work. I'd be fine with touching HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT for this, as well, but don't know the exact syntax.

By the way: It's WinXP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In two steps:

1. Open Explorer, right-click an .rcq file and choose Open, then Select from list, choose java.exe and click OK after checking "Always use the selected program".
2. Still in Explorer, open Tools -> Folder options, File types tab, click on .rcq in the list, then Advanced. Click on Open, then Edit, and add the additional parameters to the displayed command.

Comment: This works on my Vista machine (+1). Unfortunately, here I'm stuck with WinXP "Home" (which, in my experience, basically means: "Ey, user! You're so ignorant, we don't give you any advanced controls via GUI"), otherwise I'd accept the answer.

Comment: @Boldewyn: One can also do the same thru the registry. Which step doesn't work for you? And do you have regedit in Home (there are alternatives if not).

Comment: You may also copy the registry entries from the Vista machine to XP. Start with HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.rcq which will probably point to rcqfile, so you also need HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\rcqfile. Dump them to .reg files and double-click on them in XP to enter into the registry.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. There was a key `rcq_auto_file` instead of `rcqfile`, that I needed to change, but else editing the registry worked just fine.

Comment: The "File Types" tab only works for Windows XP. They removed it since Windows Vista. Now we have to modify registry ourselves.